# Javascript check rising trend in table

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.
I create this code

```
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {

    let index;
    let licznik = 0;

    for (index = 1; index < sequence.length; index++) {
        
        
          if (sequence[index - 1] >= sequence[index]) {
            sequence.splice(index - 1, 1);
            licznik++;
            index = 0;
        } else if (sequence[index] > sequence[index + 1]) {
           sequence.splice(index + 1, 1);
            licznik++;
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    if (licznik > 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work properly with table [1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6]. Any suggestions ?

Comment: To start, "return licznik  > 1" please.

Comment: On your else, you remove the 5, and not 99. You should splice the item on *index* position and not *index + 1*. But note that your approach on this matter will not work, for instance with the simple *[5, 95, 96, 6, 97]*, as removing the 6 is enough to return true, but your approach will remove 96 first.

Comment: Where is the last post ? I see it two days ago but now I can't seee

Comment: @punund `return licznik <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution, using the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method you have to iterate over your array executing three steps:

1. remove one element at every step with `splice`.
2. check if the new array obtained is sorted and if it is return the
   value `true`.
3. insert the removed element in the same position, recreating the
   original array.

The second step compares couple of arrays elements and stops once it find a couple of elements such that `sequence[i] > sequence[i + 1]`;

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {

    for (let index = 0; index < sequence.length; ++index) {
        const removed = sequence.splice(index, 1);
        let sorted = true;

        for (let j = 0; j < sequence.length - 1; ++j) {

            if (sequence[j] > sequence[j + 1]) {
                sorted = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (sorted) { return true; }

        sequence.splice(index, 0, removed);

    }

    return false;

}

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6]));
```